# How do you plot the outside of a curved line with a given thickness in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, path

I'm trying to create a line with a given thickness inside another line of a given thickness. For example,

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <path 
      stroke-width="4" stroke="black"
      d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="none" />
  </svg>
```

Is the shape of a heart with a line thickness of 4px
How do I calculate the points of a new line inside this heart line with the same thickness?

Comment: Please take a look at this demo: https://codepen.io/giaco/pen/BbpKZy. They are using the same shape scaled

Answer (score 1):

*Computing* a path at an offset from another is the domain of vector grafic editors like Illustrator or Inkscape.

If all you want to do is *rendering* something that looks like a path at an offset, a bit of masking trickery will help:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <path id="heart" stroke-linecap="square"
      d="M 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30" />
    <mask id="mask">
      <use href="#heart" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use href="#heart" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" fill="none" />
  <use href="#heart" mask="url(#mask)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="12" fill="none" />
</svg>
```