# Drawing railroad tracks in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

How would I take an arbitrary line and programmatically give it a railroad effect in SVG?

My initial thoughts were to keep the reference line invisible, and try to generate two offset paths, but reading further it seems generating offsets of bezier curves is kind of difficult.

The second approach I used in Adobe Illustrator, was to stack three strokes, including the dashed line for the crossties.  To get the transparency, I used "Knockout Group" on the opacity of the line's appearance.

I don't mind faking the look with multiple strokes, but thats not supported with SVG.

Is there a way where I can keep the single line (for use with animations and pathfinding) but programmatically generate a railroad look that follows an arbitrary path?

[image: Line over a map]
Line following route of railroad

[image: Railroad Effect]
Multiple strokes applied

[image: Railroad effect zoomed in]
Detail view of the railroad effect achieved in illustrator

Comment: Imho you should investigate HTMLCanvas

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann — Even assuming that getting the result on a canvas would suit the OP's needs: Why? Does it make solving this particular problem noticeably easier? How would you solve it using canvas?

Comment: Once again, its just my opinion. Using canvas you could easily write functions that would meet the needs of this drawing, and run them programmatically in any context. Canvas supports methods like arcTo stroke and fillRect to do exactly this. Also, you can draw images as background using canvas, making it a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base idea is the same as I've described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573933) - use a bit of trickery with masks.

The track line is defined only once, but not rendered directly. Instead, it is used as a template in three places: to define the "knockout" at the center of the track in the mask, to draw the line the knockout is applied to, and to draw the crossties.

```css
#center rect {
  fill: white;
}
#center use {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.track-lines {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  mask: url(#center);
}
.track-cross {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 7px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1px 1.8px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 60">
  <defs>
    <path id="track" d="M 40,10 H 110 C 140,10 140,50 110,50 H 40 C 10,50 10,10 40,10 Z" />
    <mask id="center">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
      <use href="#track" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use href="#track" class="track-lines" />
  <use href="#track" class="track-cross" />
</svg>
```